# Trying to create app checksum in Android, but it's not changing

Tags: java, android, apk, checksum

I'm developing an application on Android and have a legal requirement to produce an app checksum that can be recorded to check later tampering. I realise this isn't entirely secure, but I've got a box to tick!

I'm trying this, blatantly stolen from the examples at https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=java.util.zip.CheckedInputStream&method=read :

```
String apkPath = App.getContext().getPackageCodePath();
Log.i("Checksum", "getting checksum for " + apkPath);
Long chksum = null;
Log.i("Checksum", "Size: " + new File(apkPath).length());
Log.i("Checksum", "Date: " + new Date(new File(apkPath).lastModified()));

try {
    // Open the file and build a CRC32 checksum.
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(apkPath));
    CRC32 chk = new CRC32();
    CheckedInputStream cis = new CheckedInputStream(fis, chk);
    byte[] buff = new byte[80];
    while (cis.read(buff) >= 0) ;
    chksum = chk.getValue();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.i("Checksum", "Checksum is  " + chksum);
```

This runs fine and the output looks good:

```
09-27 15:17:35.775 17288-17288/com.test.checksum.checksum I/Checksum: getting checksum for /data/app/com.test.checksum.checksum-2/base.apk
09-27 15:17:35.775 17288-17288/com.test.checksum.checksum I/Checksum: Size: 3245610
09-27 15:17:35.775 17288-17288/com.test.checksum.checksum I/Checksum: Date: Wed Sep 27 15:17:03 BST 2017
09-27 15:17:37.075 17288-17288/com.test.checksum.checksum I/Checksum: And Checksum is  0DAD53E0
```

The problem is that changing the code doesn't seem to make any difference - so this code:

```
String apkPath = App.getContext().getPackageCodePath();
Log.i("Checksum", "getting checksum for " + apkPath);
Long chksum = null;
Log.i("Checksum", "Size: " + new File(apkPath).length());
Log.i("Checksum", "Date: " + new Date(new File(apkPath).lastModified()));

//do something differently
Log.i("Checksum", "And now do something else!");
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I'm doing something else!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();

try {
    // Open the file and build a CRC32 checksum.
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(apkPath));
    CRC32 chk = new CRC32();
    CheckedInputStream cis = new CheckedInputStream(fis, chk);
    byte[] buff = new byte[80];
    while (cis.read(buff) >= 0) ;
    chksum = chk.getValue();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Log.i("Checksum", "Checksum is  " + String.format("%08X", chksum));
```

Produces this output:

```
09-27 15:45:51.085 29517-29517/com.test.checksum.checksum I/Checksum: getting checksum for /data/app/com.test.checksum.checksum-2/base.apk
09-27 15:45:51.085 29517-29517/com.test.checksum.checksum I/Checksum: Size: 3245610
09-27 15:45:51.085 29517-29517/com.test.checksum.checksum I/Checksum: Date: Wed Sep 27 15:45:30 BST 2017
09-27 15:45:51.085 29517-29517/com.test.checksum.checksum I/Checksum: And now do something else!
09-27 15:45:52.335 29517-29517/com.test.checksum.checksum I/Checksum: Checksum is  0DAD53E0
```

Has anybody got any idea what's going on? Does all of the code live in this APK file, or are there more? If I use `File().list()` then I get a bunch of folders with XML files in which I'll eventually include in my checksum, but the APK file is hidden unless I access it directly by name.

Thanks,

Ben.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be something to do with running in the debugger - even with JDV's change I'm still getting 0DAD53E0 every time as the checksum, and interestingly always seeing the same file length each time too.

If I build two APK files with slightly different code and install them manually however then everything seems to work fine - installing each APK file gives a separate checksum but the checksum for each one is consistent.

I can only assume the Android Studio debugger installs a standard or core APK file and loads code from somewhere else when running in the debugger, like Visual Studio's .vshost.exe files.

Thanks for the time,

Ben.

Comment: Might be "instant run".

Answer (score 0):

The checksum should be fetched from the Stream.  i.e., to get the long value:

`cis.getChecksum().getValue()`

What you are doing is getting the same long value back from a freshly instantiated CRC32 object that is never changed.

Typically the Stream is created thusly:

`CheckedInputStream cis = new CheckedInputStream(fis, new CRC32())`

That is, the checksum you pass in is not an "out" variable. You have to fetch it from the Stream once it has been calculated.

Comment: Thank you for your help  - it looks much neater and is definitely more Android-ish. Unfortunately I'm getting exactly the same problem but I think I've found the answer (or at least a solution) it's something to do with the debugger. I'll write a separate aswer for the sake of neatness.